# What does the modulus (%) mean in this context?

Tags: jinja2

Currently a beginner using Jinja seeking some help understanding the syntax for this project. Referencing the code below, what does the % mean on both edges of the brackets? To provide context on what code below does, it's showing an search form and click to call link.

I understand it's including the html from that file, just seeking to understand the syntax.

```
<div class="ribbon-content">
   {% include 'cms/plugins/getcare/search_form.html' %}
   {% include "includes/call_pp.html" %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The {% %} is just the language syntax which holds the logic when using jinja2.

I.E
{% insert logic here %}